# Where should CORS be configured if the traffic goes to HAProxy then Nginx then Node.js?

Tags: cors

My server receives traffic via XMLHTTPRequest. The traffic goes to HAProxy -> Nginx -> Node.js.

Where should CORS be configured?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the Nginx server and Node.js application are on the internal network. So to access the application on the internet you need to configure CORS headers in HAProxy.